# Does Redis Cache in .NET Core 3 requires the usage of the Stack Exchange package?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, redis, .net-core-3.0

In .NET Core 2.2, in my `Startup.cs`, I had the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(...);             
}
```

But now, in .NET Core 3.0, the `AddDistributedRedisCache` method can't be found. In [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.rediscacheservicecollectionextensions.adddistributedrediscache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2), the "Applies to" section shows support only up to .NET Core 2.2

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1#distributed-redis-cache) from Microsoft, they use `services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache` in the example. Does it means that I'm required to install the Stack Exchange NuGet package for Redis? Why did the native Microsoft's Redis client solution removed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It took a bit of digging through their git repos, but it has been removed. The removal did not happen in the current repository, https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions, but in the previous repository, that is now archived, https://github.com/aspnet/Caching.

You can see some of the issues with the original package in this thread: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/410#issuecomment-418912525

The removal happened here: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/423

I've looked through the list of breaking changes in aspnet from 2.1 -> 2.2 and 2.2 -> 3.0 and nothing is listed for it. I'm going to create an issue on the documentation to see it included.

At this point, I believe the answer is to use the StackExchange version. It apparently has some major improvements over the older package anyway.

**UPDATE:** The latest package supported would be `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis` simply utilising this package would be best for .NET Core 3.0 and above.

Something along the lines of

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(action =>
                {
                    action.InstanceName = "WhatYouWantToNameIt";
                    action.Configuration = "127.0.0.1:6379";
                });
```

Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.stackexchangeredis?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)!

Comment: Followup: Apparently it was announced here:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/322

Comment: The link provided are not docs, just a microsoft stub page. Referring to the very last link

Comment: Here's some updated documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#distributed-redis-cache). They try to push you to Azure Cache for Redis, but they link to a github coment about doing it locally.

Answer (score 1):

To use `AddDistributedRedisCache`, you need to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` from nuget. On the other hand, if you check the document you post carefully, [AdddistributedRedisCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.rediscacheservicecollectionextensions.adddistributedrediscache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2) use [RedisCacheOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.redis.rediscacheoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2) and the [ConfigurationOptions property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.redis.rediscacheoptions.configurationoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Redis_RedisCacheOptions_ConfigurationOptions) is `StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this answer suggests the exact same link that I've posted. This NuGet package was developed for .NET Core 2.2. I would like to know if there is a Microsoft package for .NET Core 3.0 or if I must use a third party library (Stack Exchange).

Comment: @cash The package is .Net Standard 2.0 and about these link, the thing I want to point out is that even if you use `AddDistributedRedisCache` you'll still depend on StackExchange.Redis.

Comment: @LeisenChang the problem is, as stated in the link above, that the StackExchange.Redis package used in the Mirosoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis is much older and has a bug meaning it can starve the threadpool. This is a real thing.

Comment: @hrillo666, As per latest source code at https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/master/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.csproj,  The Extension doesn't depend on specific version of StackExchange.Redis Library.  Moreover the Extension is also compiled for   netstandard2.0, which helps it be referenced in .Net 3.1 as well.